# to be above board

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have made 2-year apprenticeship as a multilingual correspondent.
One expression that I came across but is still unclear to me is:

"to be above board" or "He is above board"

I have looked it up on several different platforms and haven't been able to figure out what it means.

Could someone please explain to me what it means? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

it means honest, reputable, without deceit. someone or something that is legitimate, honest and open

Comment: So, it is a positive description of a persons characteristics? Aha, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2521387: Bear in mind it's relatively uncommon to apply this idiomatic expression to a *person*. Usually it's used of *procedures, actions, arrangements* (particularly, of *financial matters*). It's a figurative C16 gambling usage - if you always keep your hands/cards *above board* (not *under the table*), everyone can see you're not cheating.

Comment: In the famous Cantina scene in the original _Star Wars_, you may recall, Han Solo is not above board in his dealings with Greedo.

Answer (score 1):

"[If things are done above board, they are carried out in a legal and proper manner](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/above+board.html)" -Meaning there is no corruption, or cheating as the origin is believed to be from gaming: [If card players keep their hands above the table (board) they can be seen to be playing fairly.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/22300.html)

Congrats on your apprenticeship!

Comment: late response from me, but thank you very much. It was worth the effort, enabling me to get in touch with ppl.